# If a character can bend a steel bar into a pretzel with little to no trouble what kinda strength level are we talking

Tags: super-powers

If I had to specify the steel bar it would be 2 inch diameter. 3 feet long. Just your average piece of steel. Round.

I guess what I'm asking is if a character can just bend this piece of steel like it's nothing, then how much force can this person exert in other situations.

Edit:
I should've clarified it would be a solid bar and the bending is done with just the hands no extra device or anything.

Also the whole body is at a similar level of strength.

Level of strength meaning, it would obviously be beyond human, forgive me because I really don't know what words to use to explain what I mean.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE Watyer, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  Can you give a bit more context for your question?  I appreciate the specs on the steel bar but I'm not sure what you're asking about strength level and other situations.  Do you want a [tag:science-based] answer with equations?  Are you trying to translate this into how the person would do in a clean and jerk competition?  Or some other measurable strength task.  Are these super arms only or is the whole body proportional?  Please edit the question to let us know.  Thanks!

Comment: Strength level five? Most people can easily bend that steel bar using the appropriate simple devices, powered by nothing more than their own muscles. I used to bend steel pipes about 1 inch in diameter with 1/6 inch thick walls (to make chair legs, workshop class at school) when I was 10, using very simple mechanical devices. If you mean "with their bare hands", then say so. As for *"how much force can this person exert in other situations"*, very obviously, at least the same force. How much is "the same force"? Well, that's a simple exercise in the strength of materials.

Comment: AlexP's comment raises another valid question: is this a *solid* steel bar, or hollow? If it's hollow, how thick are the walls?

Comment: Also, when you say 'average piece of steel', do you mean tool steel, carbon steel, stainless steel?

Comment: "*it would obviously be beyond human*" why would it be **beyond** human? The strongman that do shows have feats similar to what you describe - tearing horseshoes in two, tearing chains apart, and bending solid pieces of iron. I'm not sure if they do exactly what you want but it's definitely in the same ballpark - all stuff that normal humans aren't capable of but are still performed *by* humans.

Answer (score 5):

You could really easily get sucked down into a rabbit hole of tensile strength and varying numerical values of Pascals and Newton-meters and various other measurements of force depending on the exact steel bar in your example, but my read on your question is that's sort of not the point, so here's a few observations you may find helpful.

**It's not just about muscles.** The ENTIRE BODY of your superhero needs to stronger in order to not be damaged by the forces he's applying. Let's start with the bones. If you give someone muscles that are much, much stronger than the human norm, and you don't equally reinforce the skeletal system, you're going to just rip your tendons lose from their anchors. Reinforce those without reinforcing the bones, and they'll just break or shatter. So basically his tendons are going to be like kevlar, and his bones are going to be like steel in their own right.

You also need the skin and muscles to be a lot more resistant to compression otherwise, again, instead of bending the steel, you're going to tear the skin and muscles of your fingers off.

So, in a general sense, someone shaped like a human being who's able to bend a steel bar will also just be significantly more DENSE than a normal human would be. Therefore in addition to being able to bend things and lift things, he's also going to be able to punch holes in things fairly effectively with his fists and even his fingers. You're talking roughly about the kind of forces generated by a low-speed car crash, so anything you've seen happen to a car that was in a ~30mph crash, this guy could do with this hands.

He's going to weigh quite a lot more than a normal human does. This will make swimming more difficult. This means his terminal velocity when falling will be higher than a normal humans because mass DOES matter with wind resistance.

He's also going to be fairly bulletproof. Exactly HOW bulletproof would start to involve a lot of math, but at the very least small-caliber rounds are going to be more of an annoyance than a lethal threat. Very roughly he'd have the equivalent of a full-body suit of kevlar.

Comment: Actually, you just need to be somewhat humanly strong to bend steel. https://m.wikihow.com/Bend-Steel-With-Your-Hands

Comment: @Renan Technically correct (which is the best kind of correct), but I chose to answer the question I felt like the OP was trying to ask, rather than holding him rigidly accountable to the specific examples he chose.